# CSS changes not taking effect on production server (Bitbucket repo)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, git, bitbucket

I have a WordPress website hosted on a Linux server and connected to a Bitbucket repository and the CSS changes do not reflect on the live website.

I made changes to the HTML code and style sheet. However, when the changes are pushed, the HTML code updates instantly, but the stylesheet does not update for the longest time (Do not get me wrong here, the stylesheet updates on the GIT repo but the website does not reflect these changes immediately, takes around 4-5 hours).

I tried clearing Cache through WP-rocket plugin, Cloudflare, browser cache/cookies, nothing works. Changes that I made yesterday came up today and the changes that I made today are still not showing.

If there are any information that I can give please do let me know. I recently configured this GIT repository in the linux server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also check in function.php where enqueue scripts and styles, should be "**rand(111,9999)**". For example, custom css file have to be get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/custom.css', array(), rand(111,9999) );

Comment: Thank you @ariel. It was in fact my enqueue styles code that was causing the issue. Once I adjusted that piece of code to the above format, it worked. Thank you!